# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil' Not my url? - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Every time I try to parse my JSON file I get this error in the console:
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

People are saying it has something to do with the url and special characters but it looks like this:
http://data.myurl.com/api/49/WELOG/KRF/ticker
Any ideas?

My code:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define kLatestURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://data.myurl.com/api/49/WELOG/KRF/ticker"]

#import "ticker.h"

@implementation ticker

-(void) startTicker{
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kLatestURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(ticker:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

}
-(void) ticker:(NSData *) data{

    NSError * error;
    NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:error];

    NSArray * latestPrice = [json objectForKey:@"data"]; // under adult data
    NSNumber * value = [(NSDictionary*)[latestPrice  objectForKey:@"last_all_numbers"] 
                                                             objectForKey:@"display"];
}
```

It worked just fine earlier... I can visit the JSON file in a web browser and it works just fine.

Comment: That usually means the url you are sending isn't correct or isn't a correct JSON data.

Comment: You should set a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` (or use the "exception breakpoint" thing in Xcode) and tell us where exactly the exception is being thrown.  I think it's on the call to `JSONObjectWithData` and `data` really is nil for some reason, but let's be sure.  Also, you should be passing a handle as the third parameter of `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`, like `&error`.  Right now you're just passing the pointer, and `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` has no way to reassign your local `error` variable to point at a real error if/when something goes wrong.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint? If you set one just before you parse the JSON is the data nil?

Answer (score 0):

When I have opened `kLatestURL` I saw `Failed to load page content` message. So your JSON is not at that URL. Maybe because of some expiration date. Upload your JSON somewhere else and try again.